# F# sum machine console

Tags: recursion, f#, console, sum

I'm learning to use the console in Visual Code (F#). I want to write a code, which calculates the sum of every number I write in the console. For example, when I write 3 in the console, the code should give me back 3. After this the code ask me a next number and calculates the sum of the old result with the new number and so on. My idea was to use a recusriv function.

Here an example:

42←-

42N←-

1337←-

1379N←-

4294967296←-

4294968675N←-

5705031325←-

10000000000N←-

Here is what I tried until now:

```
let rec rechnen x =


let main(): unit =

    putline("Geben Sie Zahlen zum Addieren ein:")
    let Zahl = getline()
    rechnen(Zahl)
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question, or described why the code sample you included does not meet your needs.

Comment: And for some encouragement, a recursive function is a good way to go, keep going 

Comment: Could you please ask an answerable question of some type?

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive function should have an argument of type integer.

It have to read the input in the console (`Console.ReadLine()`) and try to parse it into an integer (`Int32.TryParse()`).

If parsing succeeded, it add the parsing result to the argument, print this sum to the console (`printfn`) and recursively call the function passing it the sum.

If parsing failed (recursion termination), you can return the argument as result or just print it.

```
let rec rechnen x =
    match Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine()) with
    | true, i -> printfn "%dN" (x + i) 
                 rechnen (x + i)
    | _       -> printfn "Gesamt: %d" x

let main(): unit =
    printfn "Geben Sie Zahlen zum Addieren ein:"
    rechnen 0
```